# Ошибка компиляции: error: not a statement human1.sayHello; ^ 1 error

Tags: java

```
public static class Human{ 
   
   public Human(String name){ 
      name = "Sergey";
   }
   public void humanAge(int age){ 
       age = 30;
   }
   public void sayHello(){
   System.out.println("Привет, меня зовут " + name + " , мне " + age + " лет.");
   }
   public static void main(String []args){
      Human human1 = new Human();
      human1.sayHello;
   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Слишком много ошибок в коде. Попробуйте так и спрашивайте, если что-то не понятно:

```
public class Human {
    
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Привет, меня зовут " + name + " , мне " + age + " лет.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human1 = new Human("Sergey", 30);
        human1.sayHello();
    }

}
```